# ¿Cómo separar la primera posición de un array?

Tags: javascript

Estoy utilizando javascript, tengo la siguiente estructura:

```js
var datos =[
      "01|FA|4.0|DEMO|162564|99|30001000000400002463||2750.00|0.00|MXN|1|2730.00|Ingreso|PPD|72010||EMISOR|H&E951128469|HERRERIA & ELECTRICOS SA DE CV|601|RECEPTOR|PASF690721EL6|FRANCISCO ALEJANDRO PAREDES SIERRA|||S01||440.00|440.00|INFO_ADIC||PROLONGACION DE LA 27 NORTE||ORQUIDEAS 620 BUGANBILIAS PUEBLA PUEBLA MEXICO C.P 72580||N ",
      "01|CFDI40|01|INFO_GLOBAL||||EMISOR||RECEPTOR|72580|626",
      "02|01|5CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A|6CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A",
      "02|04|7CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A|8CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A",
      "03|1|1|E48|F|78101800||VIAJE DE PARAFINA DEL 26 DE NOVIEMBRE DE 2021 CON 17,000 KG  DE PESO|2750.00|0.00|2750.00||02",
      "03-IMP|TRASLADO|2750.00|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00",
      "03-IMP|RETENCION|2750.00|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00",
      "03-ADU|21  80  1871  0999999",
      "04|TRASLADO|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00|2750.00",
      "04|RETENCION|002|||440.00",
      "05|1.0|20.00|0.00|",
      "05|R|Descripcion del impuesto local|0.50|20.00",
    ];
    let datosExcluidos = [];
    datos.forEach(index =>{
        var separador = index.slice(index,1);
        datosExcluidos.push(separador)
    });
    
    console.log(datosExcluidos)
```

Lo que realmente quiero es separar la primera posición, que sería algo así:

```
01 , 01, 02, 02 .....
```

Pero no he logrado realizarlo ya que solo obtengo esto:

```
["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", ...]
```

Intenté algo así `var separador = index.slice(index,1).split('|');` pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, y la verdad es que no sé cómo separar exclusivamente la primera posición antes de `|`.

Comment: `let datosExcluidos = datos.map(s => s.split("|")[0])`

Comment: Justamente lo acababa de poner y vi que ya habías respondido :D gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN:

Con split busque que extrajera todo, mientras cumpliera la condición de que si encontraba **'|'** y fuese la primera posición (posición [0] que era la que buscaba), y se le agrega al array!

```
let datosExcluidos = [];
datos.forEach(index =>{
    var separador = index.split('|')[0];
    datosExcluidos.push(separador)
});
```

Comment: En vez de crear una variable se puede hacer con un map, asi se reduce el codigo y queda mas limpio `const a = datos.map(arr => arr.split('|')[0])` de esta manera

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, lo intentare

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza expresiones regulares, en este caso comenzamos analizando el string para que comience con números (al menos uno) y se detenga cuando encuentre cualquier otro carácter que no sea un digito.

Hacerlo de esta manera te permitirá olvidarte de algunas excepciones como la variabilidad en la cantidad de dígitos.

He modificado algunos valores y puedes ver la expresión regular a continuación:

```js
var datos =[
  "01|FA|4.0|DEMO|162564|99|30001000000400002463||2750.00|0.00|MXN|1|2730.00|Ingreso|PPD|72010||EMISOR|H&E951128469|HERRERIA & ELECTRICOS SA DE CV|601|RECEPTOR|PASF690721EL6|FRANCISCO ALEJANDRO PAREDES SIERRA|||S01||440.00|440.00|INFO_ADIC||PROLONGACION DE LA 27 NORTE||ORQUIDEAS 620 BUGANBILIAS PUEBLA PUEBLA MEXICO C.P 72580||N ",
  "1005000|CFDI40|01|INFO_GLOBAL||||EMISOR||RECEPTOR|72580|626",
  "0|01|5CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A|6CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A",
  "3|04|7CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A|8CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A",
  "213203|1|1|E48|F|78101800||VIAJE DE PARAFINA DEL 26 DE NOVIEMBRE DE 2021 CON 17,000 KG  DE PESO|2750.00|0.00|2750.00||02",
  "03-IMP|TRASLADO|2750.00|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00",
  "03-IMP|RETENCION|2750.00|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00",
  "03-ADU|21  80  1871  0999999",
  "04|TRASLADO|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00|2750.00",
  "holaaaaaaaaaaa|RETENCION|002|||440.00",
  "05|1.0|20.00|0.00|",
  "05|R|Descripcion del impuesto local|0.50|20.00",
];


function getPositionFrom(text){
  const regexp = /^[\d]+/
  let matches = text.match(regexp)
  return matches
}

datos.forEach(element => { 
  console.log(getPositionFrom(element)) 
})
```

Si por algún motivo quisieras que los valores quedaran como `3` en vez de  `03` puedes castear el valor a entero con `parseInt(matches)`;

> También puedes fijarte que la función retornará `null` cuando no comience con un valor numérico, cosa que después tendrá que validar manualmente tu si utilizas `split`.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto y es muy valido, el inconveniente es que deseeo tener esta respuesta [ '01',
  '01',
  '02',
  '02',
  '03',
  '03-IMP',
  '03-IMP',
  '03-ADU',
  '04',
  '04',
  '05',
  '05' ] y no sabia como realizarla, hasta que recorde de split

Comment: He entendido mal lo que necesitabas entonces, como bien dices, split es la mejor solución para ese caso. éxito!

Answer (score 0):

También se puede hacer un poco más artesanal por ejemplo:

```
var datos =[
      "01|FA|4.0|DEMO|162564|99|30001000000400002463||2750.00|0.00|MXN|1|2730.00|Ingreso|PPD|72010||EMISOR|H&E951128469|HERRERIA & ELECTRICOS SA DE CV|601|RECEPTOR|PASF690721EL6|FRANCISCO ALEJANDRO PAREDES SIERRA|||S01||440.00|440.00|INFO_ADIC||PROLONGACION DE LA 27 NORTE||ORQUIDEAS 620 BUGANBILIAS PUEBLA PUEBLA MEXICO C.P 72580||N ",
      "01|CFDI40|01|INFO_GLOBAL||||EMISOR||RECEPTOR|72580|626",
      "02|01|5CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A|6CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A",
      "02|04|7CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A|8CB8D806-7BDF-4D24-AC4C-4C469EB4F57A",
      "03|1|1|E48|F|78101800||VIAJE DE PARAFINA DEL 26 DE NOVIEMBRE DE 2021 CON 17,000 KG  DE PESO|2750.00|0.00|2750.00||02",
      "03-IMP|TRASLADO|2750.00|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00",
      "03-IMP|RETENCION|2750.00|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00",
      "03-ADU|21  80  1871  0999999",
      "04|TRASLADO|002|Tasa|0.160000|440.00|2750.00",
      "04|RETENCION|002|||440.00",
      "05|1.0|20.00|0.00|",
      "05|R|Descripcion del impuesto local|0.50|20.00",
    ];
    let excluidos = [];
    datos.forEach(dato => {
        let corte = false;
        let prefijo = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < dato.length && !corte; i++) {
             let caracter = dato.charAt(i);
             if (caracter === '|') {
                 corte = true;
             } else {
                 prefijo += caracter;
             }
        }
            excluidos.push(prefijo);

        })
```